# MongoDB select subdocument with aggregation function

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a mongo DB collection that looks something like this:

```
{
    {
        _id: objectId('aabbccddeeff'),
        objectName: 'MyFirstObject',
        objectLength: 0xDEADBEEF,
        objectSource: 'Source1',
        accessCounter: {
                          'firstLocationCode' : 283, 
                          'secondLocationCode' : 543,
                          'ThirdLocationCode' : 564,
                          'FourthLocationCode' : 12,
                       }
    }
    ...
}
```

Now, assuming that this is not the only record in the collection and that most/all of the documents contain the accessCounter subdocument/field how will I go with selecting the x first documents where I have the most access from a specific location.

A sample "query" will be something like:

"Select the first 10 documents From myCollection where the accessCounter.firstLocationCode are the highest"

So a sample result will be X documents where the accessCounter. will be the greatest is the database.

Thank your for taking the time to read my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for an aggregation, that is a basic query:

```
db.collection.find().sort({"accessCounter.firstLocation":-1}).limit(10)
```

In order to speed this up, you should create a subdocument index on accessCounter first:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({'accessCounter':-1})
```

assuming the you want to do the same query for all locations. In case you only want to query firstLocation, create the index on `accessCounter.firstLocation`.

You can speed this up further in case you only need the `accessCounter` value by making this a so called covered query, a query of which the values to return come from the index itself. For example, when you have the subdocument indexed and you query for the top `secondLocation`s, you should be able to do a covered query with:

```
db.collection.find({},{_id:0,"accessCounter.secondLocation":1})
.sort("accessCounter.secondLocation":-1).limit(10)
```

which translates to "Get all documents ('{}'), don't return the `_id` field as you do by default ('_id:0'), get only the 'accessCounter.secondLocation' field ('accessCounter.secondLocation:1'). Sort the returned values in descending order and give me the first ten."